# getting issue while i sing "Relying party with identifier 'https://ABC.onmicrosoft.com/ABCTest' was not found."

Tags: windows, azure, ws-federation

> ACS50001: ACS50001: Relying party with identifier
>   'https://ABC.onmicrosoft.com/ABCTest' was not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while publishing to azure set your reply url to your proper application url.

if your test environment and production environment are different then while publishing to production you need to change that url to your production url insted of test url

Comment: hi mahesh, I am facing the same issue, I have set proper application URL but it is not working. It is working with one AD but is not working with another AD

Comment: ya, vinod same issue I am facing with one of my active directory. but it's working fine with other.

Comment: mahesh-then how can we solve this. I have an azure account which has two domain. First one is a temp AD which works perfectly fine while other AD which is Microsoft domain doesn't work at all. Please advise I really need this working

Comment: go to your active directory then select your application in that select configure and set "APPLICATION IS MULTI-TENANT" to YES.

Comment: Mahesh-I am not able to find MULTI-TENANT option here.

Comment: select your active-directory -> click on application tab-> select your application ->click on configure.

Comment: its not coming...its coming with my test domain but not with Microsoft domain

Comment: have you signed up your application with your Microsoft domain active directory ?

Comment: Yes, I have created the app in Microsoft AD, if you don't mind we have screen sharing at skype vinod8812

Comment: sorry, but we don't use skype in office :) we are purely Microsoft based so we use lync. may be at evening i can help. after office hours !

Comment: we also use lync probably you can join https://meet.lync.com/posh/vinod.prajapati/6G2CBCGQ

Comment: hi.. i am ready with the skype. join me on skype id: kunjadiyameet

Answer (score 0):

here is the option for multi-tenant. if you are using two active directory or more then you need to set multi tenant= yes